# How can I use memcache module in typescript?

Tags: typescript, memcached

I am working on implementing an in-memory cache feature in typescript. I settled use memcache package, `npm install memcache`. I could not find a @types/memcache.

when I try to use in my ts file, I get the following error:

```
    src/util/cache-data-store.ts:1:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'memcache'. '/Users/reza.razavipour/sandbox/gsm-unlock/node_modules/memcache/lib/memcache.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/memcache` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'memcache';`

1 import memcache from 'memcache';

Found 1 error.
```

How do I fix this error?

Also any other typescript in-memory cache that is more widely used?

Answer (score 2):

You can use memory-cache https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache
It's support Typescript and here is how you can use it:

Installation

```
yarn add memory-cache
yarn add -D @types/memory-cache
```

Usage

```
import memoryCache, { CacheClass } from 'memory-cache';

const memCache: CacheClass<string, string> = new memoryCache.Cache();

// Store a value
memCache.put('MyKey', 'My Value', duration * 1000);

// Retrieve the value
memCache.get('MyKey');
```